# How to insert data from an object into an Eclipse-generated JTable? (No databases please)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jtable

This is my first post ever on Stack Overflow, so please forgive me if I am using this list incorrectly. I am still learning the system. :P

I have a question on how to be able to create an object from another class and use that data to store it in my JTable found on BankAppGUI main class (more info found below)

Class AddAccountMenu():

```
package A09Project;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class AddAccountMenu extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2200080161616216223L;
    private JTextField initDepositField;
    private JTextField ssnField;
    private JTextField lastNField;
    private JTextField firstNField;
    private JComboBox<String> typeField;

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String ssn;
    private double amount;
    private Bank bank;
    private Customer cust;
    private Account account;

    private void cancelButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        this.dispose();
    }
```

Below here there is a block of code assigned to the JButton "Add Account..." found on the BankAppGUI.java included below.
This has many checks and balances to make sure the user input is valid.
My main issue is that below this, I want to be able to create an object out of the Customer class (which I can provide if needed) and assign that data onto the JTable that is on BankAppGUI.java. Any solutions? Let me know what I might be missing.

```
    private void finishButtonAddAccActionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        StringBuilder warnings = new StringBuilder();
        String firstName = "", lastName = "", ssn = "", depositString = "";
        double amount = 0;
        //Verify first name field
        if (firstNField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            warnings.append("First name must not be empty.\n");
        } else {
            firstName = firstNField.getText();
        }
        //Verify last name field
        if (lastNField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            warnings.append("Last name must not be empty.\n");
        } else {
            lastName = lastNField.getText();
        }
        if (!ssnField.getText().matches("\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}")) {
            warnings.append("SSN must be 9 digits, dashes are acceptable.\n");
        } else {
            ssn = ssnField.getText().replace("-", "");
        }
        //Verify initial deposit
        if (initDepositField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            warnings.append("Initial deposit must be entered.");
        } else {
            try {
                amount = Bank.round(Double.parseDouble(initDepositField.getText()), 2);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                warnings.append("Initial deposit must be a number.");
            }
        }
        if (warnings.length() > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, warnings.toString(), "Input Warnings", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            AccountType accountType = AccountType.UNDEFINED;
            if (typeField.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Checkings") {
                if (amount >= 50) {
                    accountType = AccountType.CHECKINGS;
                } else {
                    warnings.append("Checkings accounts require at least a $50 initial deposit.");
                }
            } else if (typeField.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Savings") {
                if (amount >= 25) {
                    accountType = AccountType.SAVINGS;
                } else {
                    warnings.append("Savings accounts require at least a $25 initial deposit.");
                }
            }
            if (accountType != AccountType.UNDEFINED) {
                Customer cust = new Customer(firstName, lastName, ssn, account);


                this.dispose();

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, warnings.toString(), "Input Warnings", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    }
    public void fillWithAccount(int firstName, int lastName, int ssn, int amount) {
        //this is the method that I am trying to create to initialize 
    }
    public AddAccountMenu(final javax.swing.JFrame parent, boolean modal, Bank bank) {
        super(parent, modal);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Add account...");
        setBounds(100, 100, 391, 260);
        setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        this.bank = bank;
        cust = null;
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2, 5, 5));

        JLabel fNameAddAccLabel = new JLabel("First name: ");
        getContentPane().add(fNameAddAccLabel);

        firstNField = new JTextField();
        firstNField.setToolTipText("");
        getContentPane().add(firstNField);
        firstNField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lNameAddAccLabel = new JLabel("Last name:");
        getContentPane().add(lNameAddAccLabel);

        lastNField = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().add(lastNField);
        lastNField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel ssnAddAccLabel = new JLabel("Social Security #:");
        getContentPane().add(ssnAddAccLabel);

        ssnField = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().add(ssnField);
        ssnField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel initDepositAddAccLabel = new JLabel("Initial deposit:");
        getContentPane().add(initDepositAddAccLabel);

        initDepositField = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().add(initDepositField);
        initDepositField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel acctTypeAddAccLabel = new JLabel("Account type:");
        getContentPane().add(acctTypeAddAccLabel);

        typeField = new JComboBox<String>();
        typeField.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"Checkings", "Savings"}));
        getContentPane().add(typeField);

        JButton cancelBtnAddAcc = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelBtnAddAcc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                cancelButtonActionPerformed(arg0);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(cancelBtnAddAcc);

        JButton finBtnAddAcc = new JButton("Finish");
        finBtnAddAcc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                finishButtonAddAccActionPerformed(arg0);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(finBtnAddAcc);
    }


}
```

Main class:[BankAppGUI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4NHO.png)
This class contains the main application when you first run the program, with four JButtons to choose from: Add account(which leads into the JDialog [AddAccountMenu.java] that I am stuck on trying to add object data from here onto the JTable in my main class (without using mySQL or any other databases), remove account, deposit, and withdrawal.

```
package A09Project;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GUIBankApp extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1100618131811836737L;
    private Bank bank;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable accountTable;
    private List list = new List();

    private void addAccountButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        AddAccountMenu menu = new AddAccountMenu(this, true, bank);
        menu.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUIBankApp frame = new GUIBankApp();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setTitle("Coffee Bank Unlimited™");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public GUIBankApp() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 565, 415);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        bank = new Bank();
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        exitItem.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(GUIBankApp.class.getResource("/A09Project/exitIcon.png")));
        exitItem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GUIBankApp.class.getResource("/A09Project/exitIcon.png")));
        fileMenu.add(exitItem);

        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 542, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 542, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 475, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        panel_1.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        accountTable = new JTable();
        accountTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {"Haden", "Butikofer", new Integer(8734297), null},
            },
            new String[] {
                "First Name", "Last Name", "Acct. #", "Balance"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                String.class, String.class, Integer.class, Double.class
            };
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        accountTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
        accountTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
        accountTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
        accountTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(accountTable);

        JButton btnAddAcc = new JButton("Add account...");
        btnAddAcc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                addAccountButtonActionPerformed(arg0);
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnAddAcc);

        JButton btnDelAcc = new JButton("Remove account...");
        panel.add(btnDelAcc);

        JButton btnDeposit = new JButton("Deposit funds...");
        panel.add(btnDeposit);

        JButton btnWithdraw = new JButton("Withdraw funds...");
        panel.add(btnWithdraw);
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to create an object out of the Customer class (which I can provide if needed) and assign that data onto the JTable

So then you should start by creating a `CustomTableModel`. This is a `TableModel` that holds `Customer` objects. Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step by step approach to creating a custom model.

Then in your dialog where you create the Custom object you can pass in a reference to the TableModel so that you can update the TableModel.

```
Customer cust = new Customer(firstName, lastName, ssn, account);
customTableModel.addCustomer( cust );
this.dispose();
```

Then when you display the dialog you need to add the TableModel as a parameter:

```
//AddAccountMenu menu = new AddAccountMenu(this, true, bank);
AddAccountMenu menu = new AddAccountMenu(this, true, bank, customTableModel);
```

You would now define you table something like:

```
private CustomTableModel customTableModel = new CustomTableModel();
private JTable accountable = new JTable( customTableModel );
//private JTable accountTable;
```

Just one last question. All the code in your class refers to an "Account", yet you call the business object a "Customer". I would think you should be consistent and call everything an "Account".

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am working on it as we speak! It makes a lot of sense. Just so you know, the way I coded Account.java and Customer.java, is that Account is an abstract class that uses the enum AccountType to determine whether it is a checkings or savings account, then Account is passed as a parameter in the constructor of Customer. It's a bit complicated, if this doesn't work out, I think I am definitely going to combine them all into one and get rid of the enum and abstract class and just code everything into one type of account - checkings. Thanks for the tip! It clarifies a lot!

Comment: Edit: I was able to get this to work using the CustomTableModel() class! I don't think I would've been able to figure this one out on my own. I was also still able to keep my enum values, and abstract Account class, and the AddAccountMenu class is still perfectly intact. I appreciate your help in this matter. Kudos to you!